# Turn a single array into a multidimensional array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I came across an exercise that wants me to write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a multidimensional array. Here is the starter code that is provided.

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
  // Break it up.
  return arr;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

so in this particular case, the returned array should be [[a,b],[c,d]].
I have tried using array.slice, and array.splice, and array.push but I get nothing even close to being the right answer. If anybody can help shed some light on this issue, I would be very appreciative. I have been stuck on this for days and it's getting really frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried already.

Comment: Came across an exercise? This isn't for people to do your homework. Have you tried iterating through the array using a for loop, and then stepping by the number of elements to be in the group, and creating a new array from those, and then appending the result onto a new array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best code I've ever written but here you go:

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    mda = []    
    for (i = 0; i+size < arr.length; i = i + size) { 
        mda.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    }
         mda.push(arr.slice(i));
    return mda
}
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)
```

Comment: `chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)[0]` returns `a,b`

Comment: Other than creating a new array and the for loop, I have no idea whats happening. I get that: mda.push(...) is being put into the new array, but the slice part is confusing me. Specifically: (i, i+size)); Also why is: mda.push(arr.slice(i)); outside of the for loop?

Comment: mda is the multidimensional array returned by chunk. The loop slices the original array into chunks of length "size". In slice(i, i+size) i is the beginning index and (i+size) is the ending index. Slice returns a shallow copied array between the two indicies. When the loop only has one "chunk" or a partial chunk to go, it exits. The last push to mda writes every item after the index i from the inputted array to mda.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!